# Migrar servicio de Mulestudio a WSO2

Tags: java, migration, wso2

Buenas mi pregunta es si hay alguna forma de migrar un servicio de Mulestudio a WSO2 usando cualquiera de los productos de wso2 como el carbon studio o el developer studio seria de gran ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Mule es un ESB, por lo tanto la herramienta de la suite de WSO2 que debes utilizar es el WSO2 ESB. Este es un servidor que no necesitas instalar, solo descompactas, vas a la carpeta bin, ejecutas el wso2server.bat/sh y listo.

Para el desarrollo de los servicios proxy te recomiento usar el WSO2 DeveloperStudio, que es un IDE basado en Eclipse con el plugin de WSO2 donde puedes crear un proyecto para el ESB y hacer

NOTA: asumo que con migrar quieres decir volver a reimplementar, porque alguna herramienta que migre automaticamente no creo que exista.